# Paper dialog boxes are not captured by html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, html2canvas, shadow-dom

I am using html2canvas capture the screen of a webpage the issue is `paper-dialog` boxes are not being captured by html2canvas

```
 html2canvas(document.querySelector("body")).then(function (canvas) {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

Are `paper-dialog boxes not included in the body?